# React Native - Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'singleValue.stopTracking')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lottie

I am trying to play animations individually by `item.id` in a `flatlist`. So far, I am able to bind the id and alert the correct one when I click the animation. Unfortunately, the animation does not play and I get this error `Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'singleValue.stopTracking')`.

```
    anim_star = (id) => {
  Alert.alert(id);
  this.setState({ progress: new Animated.Value(id) });
  Animated.timing(this.state.progress[id], {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
  }).start();
 }
```

Collects the id and should play the animation for which ever id was selected.

```
   data={ this.state.dataSource}

   ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


   renderItem={({item}) => <View>


   <Card>


     <View rkCardFooter>
     <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.anim_star.bind(this, item.id)}
      style={{position:'absolute',  height: '100%', width: '100%',}}>
      <Animation
      progress={this.state.progress[item.id]}
      source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute'}}
      resizeMode="contain"
      />
      </TouchableOpacity>

       <Text> Sample</Text>

     </View>

   </Card>
```

Displays an animation for how ever many categories there are.

And lastly, here is what my props and states look like:

```
    constructor(props)
{

  super(props);

  this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  id: '',
  dataSource: '',
  progress: new Animated.Value(0),
};
```

I've checked other sources and I still have no idea why this error is happening or what I am doing wrong. I figured maybe if I changed the `progress` to the id then that will trigger the animate to play individually, but that was far from correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

I would try changing anim_star like this:

```
anim_star = (id) => {
  Alert.alert(id);
  let progress = this.state.progress; <---
  progress[id] = new Animated.Value(0); <---
  this.setState({ progress }); <---
  Animated.timing(this.state.progress[id], {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
  }).start();
 }
```

And in your constructor:

```
constructor(props)
{
  super(props);

  this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  id: '',
  dataSource: '',
  progress: {}, <---
};
```

<s>Each component your flatlist is rendering should have its own state and animation logic. Additionally, you must use special tags in your render method for components you wish to animate, as well as assigning the specific state property you wish to animate as a value on a style object for the component.</s>

For example, if you wanted the opacity to change, your rendered component would look something like:

```
render() {
  return(
    <Animated.Image 
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute', opacity: this.state.progress}}
      source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
      resizeMode={`contain`}
    />
  )
}
```

Your state declaration with the Animated value and your Animated.timing() method look fine; they would just need to moved to the child component your flatlist is rendering.

Comment: I tried this, but the error still occurs and also the animation is not visible anymore. @vm909

Comment: What style property are you trying to animate? What's the effect you're looking for?

Comment: The animation itself is working, it's just that when I click to animate, everything animates at the same time. I just want that one animation to trigger and not all of them.

Comment: Oh! In anim_star, try changing this:

this.setState({ progress: new Animated.Value(id) })

to:

this.setState({ progress[id]: new Animated.Value(0) })

Comment: I think I'm getting what the problem is. Right now, your progress field is one Animated.Value. What you're trying to do is instantiate a discrete Animated.Value for each item being rendered. So you may want to change your progress field in the constructor to an empty object. That way, when you refer to `progress[id]` later on, it's referring to a field named after the given id on a state object called progress.

Comment: How would I go about changing it to an empty object? Like how would that look?

Comment: I've edited the answer to hopefully be more clear about what I'm getting at.

Comment: Ok, I changed everything including the empty object and still get that syntax error. I am thinking that bracket (`progress[id]`) is maybe not suppose to be there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170930/discussion-between-vm909-and-laney-williams).

Comment: The chat crashed I think @vm909

Comment: Also, I am no longer getting any errors. The only problem is that the animation is no longer playing.

Answer (score 1):

this happens when the first argument in your `Animated.timing` function is not a `new Animated.Value(0)`, in your case it is `this.state.progress[id]` this which I guess is causing the error